# Is passing environment variables to sapper's client side secure with Rollup Replace?

Tags: environment-variables, svelte, rollupjs, sapper

I am using replace in my rollup configuration for sapper and [sapper-environment](https://github.com/JpCapdevila/sapper-environment) to pass environment variables to the client side in sapper - is this secure? Is there a better/safer way to approach this?

Using this config below:

```
    rollup.config.js

    const sapperEnv = require('sapper-environment');    

    export default {
        client: {
            input: config.client.input(),
            output: config.client.output(),
            plugins: [
                replace({
                    ...sapperEnv(),
                    'process.browser': true,
                    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode)
                })
    ...
```

And then this allows me to use the variables in stores.js:

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
import Client from 'shopify-buy';

const key = process.env.SAPPER_APP_SHOPIFY_KEY;
const domain = process.env.SAPPER_APP_SHOPIFY_DOMAIN;

// Initialize a client
const client = Client.buildClient({
    domain: domain,
    storefrontAccessToken: key
});

export { key, domain, client };
```

I have tried running this in server,js and passing the variables through the session data, but client side no matter what I do they always seems to return 'undefined'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two questions here — a) is it secure, and b) why are the values `undefined`?

The answer to the first question is 'no'. Any time you include credentials in JavaScript that gets served to the client (or in session data), you're making those credentials available to anyone who knows how to look for them. If you need to avoid that, you'll need your server (or another server) to make requests on behalf of authenticated clients.

As for the second part, it's very hard to tell without a reproduction unfortunately!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on security. I tried to just use the environment variables in server.js and call the shopify initialize client but I think I can't pass it to the middleware as when it gets run through devalue it fails as the function contains custom classes. Is there a solution to that? I tried just exporting the returned value and it kept coming back as 'client is undefined' on the clientside.

Comment: For reference when I initialize the shopify client in server.js and try to display the variable on client side I get nothing and the console in browser reads - `TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: fs` ? Here is [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d83096f8e7864b27937d7d2132302ee5?version=3.19.2) of the code.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I just want to pass some process.env fields so I don't have to hard code an api protocol, host, and port. I'm finding it very hard to pass those to a route component. There is a preload function, but I want values to be available directly from the component.

Comment: @SMBNS you can't run a Sapper app in the REPL. Given your error message it sounds like you're importing server-specific code in parts of your app that run in the client

Comment: Thanks @RichHarris - I know it won't run in the REPL it was more to show the code I was using. I have found out the API i want to use is an unauthenticated one so can probably be passed client side safely. But I will experiment with using a server route or similar to see if I can achieve what I want.